# using HTML & CSS to display certain content on all printed pages except the first and last pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to control how an HTML page is printed in regards to which content is displayed at what page.
the content is long enough so that there is more than one paper page printed out.

I need some of the content to be displayed only on the first and last of those printed pages and for other content to be display on every page EXCEPT the first and last of those printed pages.

so I have 2 DIV elements, one is classed as "content1" and should appear only in the first page and the last page, and at the bottom of each page.
the other is classed "content2" and should appear on all pages, on the bottom of the page, except the first and last page.

```
<div class="content1">appear only in the first page and the last page, and at the bottom of each page</div>
<div class="content2">appear on all pages, on the bottom of the page, except the first and last page</div>
```

I've read the documents here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/ trying to figure out how to do so.
the

```
@page :first
```

should have worked for selecting the first page of the printed document.
so I tried this:

```
@page :first {
        .content1{
            display: none;
        }

        .content2{
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
```

but I doesn't work for me on Google Chrome for some reason.
and I couldn't find a way to select the last page.

**here is a jsfiddle link for what I tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/2xf7t3bv/3/**

is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: In your css you don't have space between `@page` and `:first`

Comment: thanks, I edited it aא jsfilddle and here in the post. it still doesn't work

Comment: seems the @page rule can only contain page properties and margin at-rules: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#syntax-page-selector so now I'm totally lost in regards to how to achieve what I'm trying to